# Sending Information from one Python file to another

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to know how to perform the below mentioned task

I want to upload a CSV file to a python script 1, then send file's path to another python script in file same folder which will perform the task and send the results to python script 1.

A working code will be very helpful or any suggestion is also helpful.

Comment: Why not just `import` the other python script normally?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the script editing the CSV to the python file and then do some sort of loop that edits the CSV file with your script 1 then does whatever else you want to do with script 2.

This is an advantage of OOP, makes these sorts of tasks very easy as you have functions set in a module python file and can create a main python file and run a bunch of functions editing CSV files this way.